# How to get the value onchange of Hidden text field value

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange, hidden

```
<input type="text" id="date-range1" class="embed width230 teaxtboxCal " style="display: none;">
```

i want to get the value in the text box whenever there is change . Actually the value is created when the calendr pop up close. how can i get the onchange function work on hidden text field.

update: i had called the trigger change in the datepicker closeDatePicker() and then i was able to use onchange function. Thanks,

```
 function closeDatePicker()
        {
            $('#date-range1').trigger('change');
            //some code //
        }
```

my only concern is i am using the id '#date-range1', but i wish there was something that triggers for all id where this is used.

anyways thanks everyone

Comment: Show us your code which you tried

Comment: @RohanKumar, Yes please drop your code. I vote it.

Comment: you need to trigger `$("#date-range1").trigger('change');`

Comment: @PraveenNagarajan What calender pop up you are using? JQuery date picker?

Comment: yea i have triggered the $("..").trigger('change') in the date picker close function . and now i can call on change function in my js file. Thanks every one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#date-range1').on('change',function(){

           alert($(this).val());
      });

});
```

this is how to do it in jquery. or just use .bind

Answer (score 1):

You can bind your input box with the `change` event

```
 $("#date-range1").bind("change",traceChange);


 function traceChange(){
      // logic comes here
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write `onchange` event for textbox..

```
<input type="text" id="date-range1" class="embed width230 teaxtboxCal " style="display: none;" onchange="abc();return false">
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >
        function abc() {
           //Do whatever you need here
        }
</script>
```

Comment: It's best to use Unobtrusive JavaScript in modern development.

Comment: @WASasquatch Tell me when `onchange` will trigger.

Comment: Its rendered as soon as its loaded, one by one in the DOM line by line. Its not a script.